# how to extend header over the page margins?

Tags: header-footer, margins, marginpar

I have defined the page margins and header as appears in the codes bellow, but I want the header to cover the page margin width too, in the pages after page 2 (all pages except the first page). I searched over the net but did not find any solution to it.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[standalone]{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a4paper,
          total=          {210mm,297mm},
          left=            37.5mm,
          right=           12.5mm,
          top=             25mm,
          bottom=          25mm,
          bindingoffset=   0mm}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\Huge \bf Title1}
\rhead{\Large \bf Title2}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.
\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\raggedleft {\large \bf Subtitle} \\*[-.8pc]}
\\Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please remove irrelevant parts of your preamble from the MWE? That makes it a lot easier for people to see what is going on quickly and to help you efficiently.

Comment: @cfr Sure, but which are irrelevant?

Comment: Which do you need to create the headers as they currently appear and which don't you? Do you have pictures in your headers? No. Hyperlinks? Symbols from `marvosym`? Surely most of your preamble is irrelevant.

Comment: @cfr I did remove all the irrelevant preamble, however, I could not remove the background package and I don't know why.

Comment: That's much better. I put the `geometry` back, though, as that will help people in this particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you would like the result to look like. I assume one of the two images but which?

Here is a start using the offset option of `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{marginnote,calc,kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{%
  left=37.5mm,
  right=12.5mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  headheight=30pt,% output from geometry tells you what this needs to be set to as a minimum
}

\newlength{\myoddoffset}
\setlength{\myoddoffset}{\marginparwidth + \marginparsep}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{\marginparsep}
\fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{\myoddoffset}
\lhead{\Huge \bfseries Title1}% Don't use \bf it is a LaTeX 2.09 command, long deprecated
\rhead{\Large \bfseries Title2}

\begin{document}

  \noindent Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.
  \reversemarginpar\marginpar{\raggedleft {\large \bfseries Subtitle} \\*[-.8pc]}
  \\Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.

  \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: offset headers]

If you add the `twoside` option to `geometry`, you'll get something like this:

[image: twoside offset]

## Update

This undoes the changes to the right offset. (You don't need to set it to zero - you just have to not change it as I did initially based on the images you posted.)

It also sets up a separate style for the first page which is applied at the beginning of the document using `\thispagestyle{}`. If you want no heading there, just use `plain` or `empty` rather than `fancyfirst` depending on whether you want a page number in the footer or not. In that case, you can dispense with the complexity introduced by defining two fancy styles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{marginnote,calc,kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{%
  left=37.5mm,
  right=12.5mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  bindingoffset=0mm,
  headheight=30pt,% output from geometry tells you what this needs to be set to as a minimum
}

\newlength{\myoddoffset}
\setlength{\myoddoffset}{\marginparwidth + \marginparsep}

\fancypagestyle{fancyfirst}{%
  \lhead{\Huge \bfseries Title1}% Don't use \bf it is a LaTeX 2.09 command, long deprecated
  \rhead{\Large \bfseries Title2}%
  \fancyheadoffset{0pt}}
\fancypagestyle{fancyoffset}{%
  \fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{\myoddoffset}%
  \lhead{\Huge \bfseries Title1}% Don't use \bf it is a LaTeX 2.09 command, long deprecated
  \rhead{\Large \bfseries Title2}}
\pagestyle{fancyoffset}

\begin{document}

  \thispagestyle{fancyfirst}

  \noindent Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.
  \reversemarginpar\marginpar{\raggedleft {\large \bfseries Subtitle} \\*[-.8pc]}
  \\Some text here.Some text here.Some text here.

  \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: fancyoffset and fancyfirst]

Comment: Thanks. I think this changes the header in the hole document. I want the first page remain unchanged.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Don't you have a title on the first page? This will not affect the page on which you have the title.

Comment: No, I don't provide any title page. Also, I think by using this method, the length of the header is changed from the right side too; I don't want the right side to be changed.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent OK. You don't use `\maketitle` at all. It changes it on the right because that is how your image suggested you wanted it. Hang on, I'll change it back.

Comment: Aha! I solved the right side problem by putting `\fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{0cm}`. My only problem is now the first page.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Please see my update.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I had questions, I will ask you later in comments... Thank you very much.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Glad that helped. Sure, let me know if you have questions. Note that I created the problem on the right because I didn't understand what you wanted from the images. You don't need to set them to 0 but only not to mess with them originally. Note that my code is commented a bit. In particular, don't use `\bf` etc. as those are deprecated. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}` etc. instead.

Comment: I used the code on my document. But, it automatically prints page numbers in the footer center, which I don't want. I have defined it in the `\rhead` separately. Also, when I add `\chead` to `\fancypagestyle{fancyoffset}` part, it also prints it on the first page. How can I solve these problems?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding `\lfoot{};
\cfoot{};
\rfoot{}` to both styles and adding `\chead{}` to the `fancyfirst` style. Is it right?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Yes. That is right. You can also put `\fancyhf{}` at the beginning of each definition to blank everything. That's what I usually do, actually.