# i want the header line to reach over both the text and the marginnotes

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, rules

I'm making a document with document class `scrreprt`, and used this to get the page numbering on the top of the pages, and a line on the top of the page

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside=semi, titlepage]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=6cm, right=2cm, heightrounded,
marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}


%% To make the marginnotes appear on the left side on all the pages
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@addmarginpar}{\ifodd\c@page}{\ifodd\c@page\@tempcnta\m@ne}{}{}
\makeatother
\reversemarginpar


\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\lehead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\rohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}
\chead{\headmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to make the line longer, so its over both the text and the margin notes?

Comment: `\setheadwidth{textwithmarginpar}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extend header over the page margins?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200914/how-to-extend-header-over-the-page-margins)

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent That question deals just with `article`; the suggested methods can be extended to the other standard classes, but `scrreprt` is a different animal.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `headwidth` to `textwithmarginpar` and then use different offsets for the header on even and odd pages (possible with KOMA-Script version 3.14 or newer).

```
headwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\the\marginparwidth-\the\marginparsep:marginpar
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi, titlepage]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
  vmargin=2.5cm, heightrounded,
  left=6cm, right=2cm,
  marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm
]{geometry}

\reversemarginpar

\usepackage[
    automark,
    headsepline,
    headwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\the\marginparwidth-\the\marginparsep:marginpar
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\Blindtext\marginpar{Margin text}
\Blindtext\marginpar{Margin text}
\Blindtext[1]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know this answer is five months old. But. The picture is exactly what i want! :D But when i add the code you wrote (and only your code in a new document) i don't get the same document as you have one the picture. The head line on the even numbered pages is starting right over the text and disappears outside the page on the right. How do i ajust so the line works on even numbered pages too?

Comment: Using KOMA-Script Version 3.16 (current in MiKTeX and in TL2014) or 3.17a (current in TL2015 and on CTAN) I get still the same document as in my picture. So, which KOMA-Script version do you use? And note that you need version 3.14 or newer and that `twoside=semi` is used in the example.

Comment: But how do i update? i cant figure out how. I use windows and miktex. I opended package manager (miktex) and searched for koma-srcipt. i thought i could a it, and then install it, but that option isn't available :S If you could help me with describing how to fix this i would be so grateful!

Comment: @landigio Use the MiKTeX update manager: see the [MiKTeX Manual](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/updating.html). If you have a muliuser Installation you should do it both in admin and user mode. And see also [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/43317)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful, I finally got it to work! :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the header to include the marginpar as well.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside=semi, titlepage]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\setheadwidth{textwithmarginpar}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Now, why doesn't it work loading `geometry`?

```
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=6cm, right=2cm, heightrounded,
marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
```

Adding the option `showframe` shows us one simple thing. Headers and footers are treated like left- and right-hand pages. But global option `twoside=semi` makes all pages in concern of margins odd (right-hand pages). Telling geometry to use a right margin of 2cm means, the text earea is two centi meter away from the page boundary, but you requested a marginpar width of 3.5 cm with an additional sep of half a centi meter. That means the width of the head is extenden about 2 cm outside of the physical paper (or pdf). You can easily test this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside=semi, titlepage]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=6cm, right=2cm,heightrounded,
marginparwidth=3.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\setheadwidth{textwithmarginpar}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\marginpar{Where the duck is the rest of this text?}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get the marginpar smaller, of course, but i think you shouldn't use them anymore.

[image]

Comment: yes this works! but only on the even numbered pages.. :/ thank you very much for fast answer!

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Do you have a recent KOMA-script? http://www.komascript.de/current Might have been a bug in an older version.

Comment: Think i found the problem. I think it is my options on the geometry pack that messes things up. i added my geometry package settings on my origninal question on the top (sorry for not adding it from the start).

Comment: do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: @landigio I don't know if you get pinged when edits happen, so ^^^^

Comment: im sorry, i have understood that i may have done things a bit difficult for my self making my document. The reason i have the margins that way is because i want all the marginnotes to appear on the right side, and i have actually figured out how to make the margins appear on the right side (they dont disappear outside the document, i can add my code for this over), so thats not a problem. i just don't know how to make the header line don't end up outside the document (on odd numbered pages). Thank you so much for your help anyway!

Comment: @landigio You could define a clone layer for every page (odd, even) and
define the sepline for any possible case. But i sense using
option `twoside=semi` and `\reversemarginpar` has it's reason.
Can you explain your goal? We might find a better solution. Doing
it for a one sided document is easy, for a twosided as well. But
not for `semi`.

Comment: my goal is to make the document so the marginnotes appears on the left side on all the pages (i want the thick margin on the left side). but i want the pagenumbers to appear on the top of the page, on the left side on even numbered pages, and on the right side on odd numbered pages. I also want the head line to reach over the margin.

Comment: @landigio You are aware that this layout is quite unusual?

Comment: yeah i didn't know when i started, but i have realised that now. i hoped it would be possible anyway though.

Comment: And you really want to have the document `twoside`ed? Meaning text on both sides of the pages?

Comment: the option `twoside=semi` was something i used to get the pagenumering on the left side on even numbered pages, and on the right on odd numbered pages. i really don't know much about latex yet, and thought i had to use it to get the page numbering the way i wanted. i guess it doesn't matter if i use the `twoside` option if i still get the pagenumbering the way i want.

Comment: So, you basically want the pagenumber on the *outside*?

Comment: hmm here is another question i asked, on the picture you can see what i have in mind. [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209365/how-do-i-add-a-blue-box-around-the-section-number]